# Jquery if div has value1-10 add class

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to build this reputation bar for my site which will solely depend only on given number. The functionality should be something like this.

If div has value 1-10, add `class="beginner"`
If div has value 11-20, add `class="mediocre"`
If div has value 21-30, add `class="hardcore"` 
and so on..

I have this:

```
<div><a>7</a></div>
```

What I want is this:

```
<div class="beginner"><a>7</a></div>
```

I thought I should start with something like this:

```
$("div:contains('0>10')").addClass("begginer");
```

but I am pretty much sure that's not going to work. Can anyone help me with this? I am pretty lost here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ocuqem/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
var rated = $('div a');                  // SET YOUR 'numbers' source
var r = parseInt( rated.text(), 10 );    // parse integers with radix
var rate = 'beginner';                   // SET INITIAL RATE

  if ((r > 10) && (r <= 20)) { rate = 'mediocre'; }
  if ((r > 20) && (r <= 30)) { rate = 'hardcore'; } 

rated.addClass(rate);                    // FINALLY ADDCLASS TO ELEMENT
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to ask. I also wanted to append append certain text beside that 7, say "Level 1". Is it possible?

Comment: Just added this code to my javascript file like this(Not working):

`jQuery(function(){
var rated = $('#userlvl div a');
var r = parseInt( rated.text(), 10 );
var rate = 'beginner';
var text = 'level 1';

if ((r > 10) && (r <= 20)) { rate = 'mediocre'; text='level 2'; }
if ((r > 20) && (r <= 30)) { rate = 'hardcore'; text='level 3'; } 

rated.addClass(rate).parent().append(text);

});`

Comment: Here it works:http://jsbin.com/ocuqem/6/edit What is actually not working on your side? Can you create a test case on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) ?

Comment: roxon the code is not working when there is a list of numbers. If the first div has level 3, all the other div also get level 3 no matter how big or how small the number the other divs have... Do you know how to fix this? Maybe throwing a .each function somewhere in the code or something...

Comment: Sure. Use the .each function! But in that case you have to set a CLASS for the parent, instead of  ID (I changed #rating to .rating) http://jsbin.com/ocuqem/7/edit Happy coding friend! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort. but its not working for me :( Can you take a look at my code: http://jsbin.com/ufayim/2/edit

Comment: Your script is missing the programming point. I'll re-write it in a cool way with just few lines of code. May you just please tell me the 10-color-steps? `level1` is `#cfdcb9` .. what are the other colors? (and btw you are missing the levels for colors in your CSS that's why you could not apply the classes. Cause they don't exist! And you forget to add jQuery in your jsBin, and you are not assigning programmatically classes to spans either. )

Comment: You want to go from green to red (for lvl 10?) ?

Comment: OMG! thank you so much mate. My css is missing cuz It was just a sample. I just wanted to the jquery code to work first then take care of the css. lets say theres going to be 50 levels. the difference between each level will be 200 points. and each level will have 5 sub-levels, for example lvl1-1, lvl1-2, lvl1-3, lvl1-4, lvl1-5, so its easier for me to style the progess bar. all the lvl1s will have say, green. I am not sure about the other 49 level's color yet. I wish to get all the style work done in css and not forced by the javascript.Let me know if I am not clear. :) thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.filter()`:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  var number = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);

  return (number >= 1) && (number <= 10);
}).addClass("beginner");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function() {
    var cssClasses = ['beginner','mediocre','hardcore','genius','mad-wizard'];
    $('div').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).find('a').text();
        index = (index.length === 1) ? index = '0' : index = index.substr(0,1);
        $(this).addClass( cssClasses[parseInt(index)] );
    });
})();

// weird i know
// this is assuming you don't go past 2 digits in value

// this is wrong, its doing 0-9, 10-19, 20-21   sorry
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll nedd custom code to deal with this. An example would be:

```
$("div").addClass(function(index,currentClass) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).children("a").text(), 10);
    if ( value <= 10 )
        return 'beginner'
    if ( value <= 20 )
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do an `if` statement with matching instead.

```
var val = parseInt( $('div').text() );
if ( val  <= 10 ) {
    // ...
} else if ( val <= 20 ) {
    // ...
}
```

And if you want to do this for a set of `<div>`s, you can use

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var val = parseInt( $(this).text() );
    // ...
```